# Installing CU after installing Service pack 1

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update, service-pack

It seems the version of SharePoint 2013 server on my dev machine was that of RTM. So I installed Service pack 1 from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42544)

Now I see the version is:

```
DisplayName    : Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4571.1502
```

I tried to install CU [Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3055009)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48560) , but I get the following message:

```
Update for Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB3055009) 64-Bit Edition
---------------------------
The expected version of the product was not found on the system.
```

Using powershell script I got this information about my Products and Language Packs:

```
Products and Language Packs
-------------------------------------------


DisplayName    : Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4571.1502

DisplayName    : Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013  - German/Deutsch
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4420.1017

DisplayName    : Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013  - English
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4569.1506

DisplayName    : Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013  - French/Français
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4420.1017

DisplayName    : Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013  - Dutch/Nederlands
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4420.1017

DisplayName    : Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4569.1506

DisplayName    : Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013
DisplayVersion : 15.0.4569.1506
```

Which CU should I install now? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: https://blog.imason.com/fully-patch-sharepoint-2013-with-sp1/

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1ae6e4df-488c-463f-98a8-f4021ad9d5d0/correct-way-to-install-share-point-2013-on-windows-2012-r2?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Dumb question, I'm sure, but did you run psconfig after you installed the CU?

Comment: Try Get-SPProduct -Local in PowerShell and run SP Config Wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem I was facing but this might not apply to other people. My case was a bit special.

I tried to install service pack 1 for each language pack as was suggested above, but every time I ran the exe it would tell me that it is already installed.

I decided to remove each language pack one by one and reinstall them again. And this time the CU were installed.

One more thing, I had to increase the size of my virtual disk to allow the CU to be installed.

Comment: Installing Server SP1 actually does not include Language pack SP1. You need to install LP SP1 separately as @adilahmed mentioned. Hope this clarifies any confusion.

Comment: What I am suspecting...did u download fresh bits for language pack? If yes those are already have sp1 in it...so those solve ur purpose

Answer (score 2):

Hi also you need to install service pack 1 for your language packs and after try to install CU

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42082

change to your language pack

Comment: service packs are installed when during installation of Service Pack 1.